# Custom features with custom rendering section in Sitecore SxA Toolbox

Tags: sxa, best-practices

What is the best practice to create a custom toolbox section in SXA?

I am looking to reuse promo rendering under this custom components section.

Is this something which can be achieved without editing the code?

Also will it overwrite/delete the custom component section when upgrading to next Sitecore or SXA version ?

Comment: you wanted to create new tab in list of available tabs like Social/PageContent or any other things. Can you please provide more details or any screenshot for reference?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you want to start creating your own custom renderings (completely new one or by cloning existing one) I would suggest creating a new feature. SXA has scripts for this, take a look:

[image]

Then you can simply extend your Site with this feature, there is also a script for this:

[image]

Ok, you have your new feature (the place where you will be creating your own renderings) so you can easily create new toolbox section. The tricky thing is that it will be created not from the name of an item under `/sitecore/content/Tenant/Site/Presentation/Available Renderings` but the name will be taken from an item under which you've stored your rendering. So:

1. Create a rendering:

[image]

2. Add it to available renderings (under your site):

[image]

3. Done

Comment: Will it overwrite this custom feature when upgrading to next version of Sitecore or SXA?

Comment: No - it will be safe:)